# Gradle keeps using wrong java version

Tags: java, linux, gradle

I'm really sorry to ask this question, since there's already multiple questions about this exact topic. I tried everything I found so far, but nothing seemed to work.

We build our project with Gradle and it's running on Java 8.
I had to install Java 17 for a new project I'm working on and since then Gradle keeps using Java 17, when it shouldn't.

My `JAVA_HOME` is set to 1.8 and the default `java` is also 1.8.
After reading loads and loads of topics here, I also tried setting `org.gradle.java.home` in the `gradle.properties` file.
But neither on project-level nor on user-level; gradle keeps using 1.17.
Now I also installed `jenv` to define an explicit java version on my project-folder. And even though the local, but also the global, java version is set to 1.8 it doesn't change for gradle.

It keeps defaulting to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64`.

The only way it seemed to work, is when I run the gradle command with the argument to set the system variable 
(`./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/path/to/jdk`)

Has anyone had a similar problem or knows, why gradle isn't using the `java.home` I declared in the `gradle.properties`? 
I know that gradle reads the project-level `gradle.properties`, since it includes user/password for our maven repository.

Edit (comment of @joachim-sauer):

1. I launch gradle via terminal and use a wrapper, so the exact command is `./gradlew [command]`
2. `which java` outputs to `/home/user/.jenv/shims` (due to the installation of jenv), whereas `java -version` outputs `java version "1.8.0_181"`
3. I didn't explicitly enable or disable daemon-mode, so I guess by default it's enabled?
4. gradle fails to build, the error occurs due to a missing package, which was removed since java 11. I also tried logging it, adding `println(System.getProperty("java.home")`  to my `build.gradle`. This also outputs `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64`

Best regards
3m7ecc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide answers to: 1. How do you launch gradle? Give the exact command line, if applicable. 2. What's the output of `which java`? 3. Did you disable daemon mode in Gradle? 4. How do you verify that the wrong Java version is used?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I added the information !

Comment: My understanding is that in Gradle, there is both a Client VM (i.e. the wrapper application), a daemon VM (the main orchestrator) and a worker VM (the compiler) that all might use different versions of Java, depending on the configuration. And I am not sure which one is wrong. Is the output of `./gradlew --version` also Java 17? (It should be controlled with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.)

Comment: @BjørnVester `./gradlew --version` outputs, that it uses `1.8.0`. It only seems to be the compiler, that (wherever it may get this information) keeps on using java 17.